# Running tasklist in windows service converted from jar

Tags: java, windows-services, tasklist, java-service-wrapper

I have java code which runs tasklist and everything works fine.

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("tasklist");
command.add("/s");
command.add(device);
command.add("/u");
command.add(user);
command.add("/p");
command.add(pass);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);

Process p;
try {
    p = pb.start();     
    //tasklistResult = 1 when run as a service. 0 when run as jar.
    int tasklistResult= p.waitFor();            
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, once I convert the jar to a windows service using, Java Service Wrapper, tasklist no longer works on remote computers. I receive the error, "ERROR: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." The same problem/error occurs when I use systeminfo remotely too. I am positive the username/password are correct.

The program works as a service if I do not remote into computers. Pinging also works as a service. How can I get the service to properly run tasklist and systeminfo remotely??

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the account under which the service runs to the current running administrator account. Now the service runs properly, but it still has trouble starting on computer boot because the network is unreachable until I log in...

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-account.html

In the .conf file... add/modify the following

wrapper.ntservice.account=.\
wrapper.ntservice.password=